# Вопрос о запятых

Tags: пунктуация

Скажите, пожалуйста; в этом бесспорно странном предложении видим 2 запятые. Они нужны? Если да, то почему? Если нет, то почему?

Благодаря качественно выполненному и спроектированному наружному освещению, находиться на участке становится комфортно, даже ночью. ©

Заранее большое спасибо за ответ.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Может, ещё мнения?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ... деепричастные обороты не обособляются.., если деепричастие
>   утратило глагольное значение; так, простые отглагольные ***предлоги
>   благодаря, включая, исключая, кончая, начиная, считая, спустя и
>   составные отглагольные предлоги смотря по, судя по, невзирая на,
>   несмотря на, не доходя до, исходя из, начиная с*** вместе с
>   относящимися к ним словами не образуют деепричастных оборотов и **не
>   обособляются...**
>
> ***Возможность обособления подобных оборотов связана с условиями контекста. Они могут обособляться,*** если деепричастие в составе
>   оборота употребляется в своем прямом значении, если носит характер
>   **уточнения, попутного пояснения** или если **не утратило значения времени**.

[Розенталь Д.Э. §95. Обособленные дополнения](http://evartist.narod.ru/text1/45.htm#%D0%B7_04)

В вашем предложении нет необходимости ставить запятые, но они возможны, если вы хотите придать обособленным конструкциям интонационную выразительность (первая запятая) и уточняющее значение (вторая запятая).

Comment: Очень детальный и понятный ответ. Благодарю Вас!

Answer (score 2):

Запятые не нужны, но возможны. Первая отделяет распространенный обстоятельственный оборот, её можно убрать без потери смысла, но читать станет не так комфортно.
А вот вторая, перед "даже", несет некоторый смысл. Здесь показывается что "даже ночью" - самостоятельное условие, усиление сказанного, а не просто уточняющее обстоятельство, перед "даже" - интонационная пауза.
В принципе, тоже можно обойтись без неё.

Другими словами: обе запятые - на усмотрение автора.

Comment: Понятно, спасибо большое!

Answer (score 0):

Тот же объем информации можно передать следующим образом:

Качественно  выполненное  наружное освещение обеспечивает комфортное пребывание на участке, в том числе  в ночное время.

Comment: Да, несомненно так. Просто вокруг первоначального «чернового» варианта и завязался спор.